# SQLITE query, return records from multiple tables each joining their own metatable

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am developing a new database backend for my application for more flexibility.

Instead of one large table with many columns, I now have four tables;

- Table "roms" (contains a single column 'Name')
- Table "romsmeta" (contains columns 'Name','Title','Year')
- Table "software" (contains columns 'System' and 'Name')
- Table "softwaremeta" (contains columns 'System','Name','Title','Year')

So now I need to use a JOIN type in my queries, but my skills are a bit rusty. Basically, I would like to perform the following pseudo-query;

SELECT Title,Year from (roms INNER JOIN romsmeta,software INNER join softwaremeta) WHERE Title like '%enteredTitle%'

Obviously, this syntax is not valid.

What query would return the results I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
SELECT rm.Title, rm.Year 
from roms r
inner join romsmeta rm
on r.name = rm.name
inner join software s
on s.name = rm.name
inner join softwaremeta sm
on sm.name = rm.name
WHERE rm.Title like '%enteredTitle%'
```

Comment: Hmm, this returns "ambiguous column name: Title: SELECT Title,Year"

Comment: Ok, I was missing the rm prefix. It should work now.

Comment: Hmm, this returns what appears to be the correct amount of results (those from table roms and software), but the Title/Year values are all the same.

Comment: Maybe you want the data from the softwaremeta table, then change the first line from rm.Title, rm.Year to sm.Title, sm.Year